# How to execute Javascript or jQuery on newly opened popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(e) { function clickme() { alert('heyy'); } )};
```

HTML in the popup:

```
<li id="tab2" onclick="clickme()"><a href="#">example</a></li>
```

Comment: And where's the non-working code ?

Comment: what you have tried for it???

Comment: console shows that functions are not defined. I'm just trying to execute a very simple function which include alert() function inside. and giving a specific button onclick="" to run the code, It says function isn't defined.

js/jQuery:


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

       function clickme() {

alert('heyy');

       }
)};

html in the popup:

 <li id="tab2" onclick="clickme()"><a href="#">example</a></li>

Comment: Added the response from the comment into the question

Comment: You define the function in an inner scope (`$.ready(function(){})` creates private scope), then try to call it globally. You can't do this. Instead, remove the inline `onclick` attribute (handler) and use `$('#tab2').on('click', function(){alert('heyy');});` from within the `$.ready()` block instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "popup"? Do you mean a new window (e.g., opened using `window.open()`? Or do you mean a popup constructed using any of a number of widget factories along the line of a jQuery UI Dialog? The answer will vary greatly. Also, did @JaredFarrish's comment help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) you can use this :

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for ready 
});
```

Which is equivalent to :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "p" ).text( "The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated." );
});
```